# How to read custom namespace nodes in Inline SVG in HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an inline SVG embedded in HTML like the following:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:myapp2="http://example.org/myapp2" height="200px" width="200px">
    <rect id="myRect" height="100px" width="100px" fill="blue" myapp2:height="200px" xlink:href="ok"/>
    <myapp:piechart xmlns:myapp="http://example.org/myapp"
    title="Sales by Region">
        <myapp:pieslice label="Northern Region" value="1.23"/>
    </myapp:piechart>
</svg>
<script>
var rect = document.getElementById("myRect");
var rectHeight = rect.getAttribute('height'); // returns 100px
var rectHref = rect.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href'); // returns ok
var rectMyApp2Height = rect.getAttributeNS('http://example.org/myapp2', 'height'); // returns null
var rectPiechartLen = rect.getElementsByTagNameNS('http://example.org/myapp', 'piechart').length; // returns 0
</script>
```

I can't read values of nodes from custom namespaces myapp and myapp2.
Why the value of rectMyApp2Height is null?
Why the value of rectPiechartLen is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html5 does not support custom namespaces, only svg, mathml and xml.

You'll need to serve the document with some xml mime type e.g. text/xml to have namespace support.